# Change date format to import into Mysql

Tags: php, xml, datetime, date-conversion

I need help changing this date format:

I get it in a XML format that looks like this: `15 08 14`. I am trying to import it to MySQL with PHP and my code looks like this:

```
$Date = date_format(date_create_from_format('%d %m %Y', $record->Date), 'Y-m-d');
```

But it doesn't work I keep getting errors:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime

Comment: Your code should be `date_format(date_create_from_format('%d %m %y', $record->Date), 'Y-m-d');` NOTE the `lower case` `y`

Comment: Also looked into that but still gave the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(' ', ':', $record->Date)));
```

**EDIT**
The problem was that the spaces in the original date format, prevented PHP from recognizing any date format related.

However, this might not be the most elegant answer, if someone else has a better way of detecting your date format (the one retrieved from the XML doc) that suggestion should be used.

Comment: This works, thanks. But now I am happy that it wrote it into the database, but for some odd reason it is display a very very old date and not the current date when the file was last modified?

Comment: Let me guess, it's 1970-01-01?

Comment: Affirm sir, exactly that date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$Dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d m y', $record->Date);
echo $Dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using a datetime field from a mysql database e.g. "2012-03-24 17:45:12"

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row[0]);

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
#output: 2012-03-24 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
#output: 24/03/2012 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
#output: 24/03/12

echo date_format($date, 'g:i A');
#output: 5:45 PM

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
#output: 05:45pm

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
#output: 5:45pm on Saturday 24th March 2012

?>
```

[PHP REFRENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)